# Panning de background após efeito keydown

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Algo está errado no método que estou usando para recriar o efeito do JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LeoTheTitan/9Ttk5/

Quero que o background se mova em 10 pixels na direção do keydown, e que continue se movendo em loop conforme a tecla seja novamente pressionada ou mantida. Sei que o código abaixo não observa o fator "tecla mantida pressionada" - alguém pode me ajudar a implementar essa parte?

O efeito deve funcionar no eixo x e y e deve ser possível também na diagonal.

Segue o código:

HTML

```
<div id="pageBg"></div>
```

CSS

```
#pageBg {
background: url('http://placekitten.com/2000/2000') repeat 0 0 fixed;
height: 600px;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var xPos = "background-position-x";
var yPos = "background-position-y";

window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { //Left Arrow Key
            $('#pageBg').css(xPos, $('#pageBg').css(xPos) -10 + 'px');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { //Up Arrow Key
            $('#pageBg').css(yPos, $('#pageBg').css(yPos) -10 + 'px');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { //Right Arrow Key
            $('#pageBg').css(xPos, $('#pageBg').css(xPos) +10 + 'px');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { //Down Arrow Key
            $('#pageBg').css(yPos, $('#pageBg').css(yPos) +10 + 'px');
    }
});
```

Comment: O seu exemplo nem funciona aqui: as propriedades que você está usando foram idealizadas como parte do CSS3 mas foram rejeitadas posteriormente. Você terá que alterar x e y individualmente.

Comment: Me desculpem caso não entendam a última sentença, queria dizer alterá-las em conjunto, não individualmente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheguei nesse resultado: http://jsfiddle.net/95GhY/3/

Criei vetores de velocidade e posição, caso as teclas sejam pressionadas a velocidade irá alterar conforme configurado pelo mapeamento de teclas e iniciar um loop pelo `setInterval`.

Enquanto a velocidade for diferente de zero esse loop estará rodando a cada 10ms atualizando a posição da imagem. Para melhor performance utilizar o `requestAnimationFrame`, porém ele não é suportado em todos os navegadores.

Comment: Excelente! Seu código tem bastante elegância para lidar com a questão. Sem lags e sem efeitos indesejados de queue de animação. Respondido com maestria. Ainda, note que alterar os valores no array de velocidade permite criarmos um background com panning automático. Acabou matando dois coelhos com uma cajadada só. Ab.